# MVC web application in the global.asax, when session time out how to get the cookie value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, global-asax, session-timeout

everyone, I am a new comer.Hope you could help me, thanks in advance.

Now I meet a problem, for the MVC web application in the global.asax, when session time out how to get the cookie value which I set it's value in some controller;

I've tried in the event Session_End()&Session_Start(), but I'm not sure how to get cookie value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a cookie from Session_End, because Session_End is not fired from a user request, that means it can't read something that is stored on the user's browser.
But you could store some data on the Session object:

```
//Inside your controller
Session["YourData"] = "Some value";
```

And then get it on the Session_End event:

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var someValue = (string)Session["YourData"];
    //do something with someValue
}
```

I hope this helps